# NLog time formatting

Tags: nlog

How do I write a layout for NLog that outputs time with milliseconds like this `11:32:08:123`?
I use `${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss}` but I need more time precision in my logs.

Comment: If you happen to be looking for a time only long format, use `${time}`. (How did I not spot this last time I searched? [NLog Layout-Renderers](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers))

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}`

According to the [NLog documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Date-layout-renderer), you can use C# DateTime format string.

This is a pretty good reference for DateTime format strings: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 12):

```
${longdate}
```

Another alternative to the format suggested by harriyott is to use the ${longdate} renderer. It should automatically give you the precision you need.

Comment: `${longdate}` works great, but be aware that you *must* define the database column as `datetime2` rather than `datetime` or NLog will throw an exception when you try to store the `longdate` value.

Answer (score 11):

Another alternative solution is to use the ISO 8601 format '1998-02-23T14:23:05.555'. This format is independet of the languange of the sql server.

```
${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fff}
```